# Miniconda cannot create an environment with Python 3.7 installed in it (macOS Monterey M1 chip)

Tags: python, apple-m1, miniconda, macos-monterey

I am trying to create an environment in miniconda with python 3.7 in my macbook air(macOS Monterey Apple M1 chip) as below,

conda create --new newenv python=3.7

However I get the below error-

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

- python=3.7

I have tried conda-forge and got the same error

I understand that this is because of the M1 chip and I have to maybe create osx-64 environment, but is there any easy way to do it?

My need is to create a miniconda environment with python 3.7 in it.

Answer (score -1):

I got the same problem when I used my MBP (14 inch, M1 Pro chip) to create an Anaconda environment (python 3.7).

However when I changed to python 3.8 and used the `conda-forge` channel (added the `-c` argument to `conda-forge`), it worked!

**The command is as follows:**
`conda create -n env -c conda-forge python=3.8`

I think maybe python 3.7 is no longer supported by m chips.